# How to standardize data with a certain mean and standard deviation value

Tags: python, scikit-learn, preprocessor, standardized

How do I standardize a dataset with a certain mean and standard deviation value?

I know there exists packages like `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` but this package only allows us to standardize the dataset using the dataset's own mean and standard deviation value. What if I want to standardize the dataset using my own specified mean and standard deviation value?

Is there a package in Python I could use? Otherwise, a way I could think of is to do this manually for each feature (ie. `(X-mean)/(stddev)` for each feature in the dataset, where `mean`=my own specified mean value, `stddev`=my own specified standard deviation value).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler exists is for things like on-demand-data machine learning and such. It is used in pipelines. It does work by itself, but that is a using a sludge hammer on a tac. The way you described is the only way to rescale data as you see fit with your own parameters. My only recommendation would be to use array's; since arrays project their operations to all their entries automatically, so the code looks nicer.

```
import numpy

data = numpy.array([1,2,3,34,2,2,3,43,4,3,2,3,4,4,5,56,6,43,32,2,2])

#Custom mean and std.
new_data = (data-10)/5

#Using the array's mean and std. 
new_data = (data-data.mean())/data.std()
```

Comment: what is the mean and std that you tried to accomplish?
seems like your code does not work.